# Extract Value from a XML Attribute with xpath/c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, ssis

i am currently working on  extracting data from a XML file with xpath and C# in a script task in SSIS.
I want to fill this infomation into a SQL table later.

My Input Xml-file looks like this

```
<Order>
<Header dateOfExecution="2017-06-22 08:30:09" orderId="5000206348" status="O" messageId="1" type="REQ" serviceProviderId="SP010" externalId1="b0ddcfece1a345338f20902401fa1e71" />
<Body>
    <Oli>
        <OliControl oliId="1" subscriptionId="990448" />
        <MIGOPT>
            <MigratedOptions>
                <Option operation="CHG" optionType="FLNDetails" optionId="O2O0056">
                    <Attribute name="fixedLineOption" value="2" />
                    <Attribute name="portingDate" value="2017-07-03 06:00:00" />
                    <Attribute name="portingWindow" value="06:00:00" />
                    <Attribute name="fixedLineSource" value="D001" />
                    <Attribute name="fixedLineType" value="Analog" />
                    <Attribute name="fixedLineNumber" value="490" />
                    <Attribute name="LAC" value="06736" />
                </Option>
            </MigratedOptions>
        </MIGOPT>
    </Oli>
</Body>
</Order>
```

i manage to get the value of "type" from the header with

```
 string  type = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Header/@type").InnerText;
```

but somehow the functions doesn't work when i am trying to get the values from every Attribute

```
 string portingDate = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Attribute[name='portingDate']/@value").InnerText;
```

where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing `@` before `name`. Change it like this:

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("//Attribute[@name='portingDate']/@value");
```